# Where do I put my layout in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Starting from opening a new file with a blank activity, where do I put the XML view groups for android apps?

[image]

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: what folder do i put the xml layouts in?

Comment: obviously in `res > layout` folder.

Comment: app/res/layout/your_xml_file.xml

Comment: Do not jump in ans start studying 'Z' instead of 'A'. Start from here https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: I don't see the layout folder for some reason. I already work in PHP/HTML, but now I'm adding android to my skill set, because I'm unable to find work after time in the service.

Comment: find that reason then or post your screen shots

Comment: @acoder what have you Googled so far about this issue? Please always show your research when asking a question.

Comment: No clue yet as to why it's not there yet.

Comment: layout folder is just a simple folder. See the comment by [Shashank Udupa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474305/where-do-i-put-my-layout-in-android-studio#comment58643269_35474305) above.

Comment: you can create layout folder too but if it is not present from start I would recommend to create another new project

Comment: Yes, I googled the issue, but it wasn't coming up on top on google. I hand created it now.

Comment: Right click in `res`...new folder, name it `layout` that's all

Comment: I created it already, and it didn't show up because I chose to do a blank view

Comment: change the view, android to project

Comment: Can I delete this question to try to remove the ban, or how should I edit it to get more up votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no layout folder, you should create one and then create the xml file inside that(You would need to inflate that xml through your java code).

If you already have a xml file and it's not showing because of some reason then you need to check whether you have selected "Android" or not. See the image.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I noticed after selecting an option it created a layout folder in the res folder.

Comment: Yeah, it does. When you create a new project in Android Studio, it creates the necessary folder automatically. Btw, if you see folders such as color and all in some tutorials or anything, feel free to create one as those are generally manually created. Btw, if it solved your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the project, then creating a new one when selecting an option other than blank project.